# gradually Increment the opacity for etch-a-sketch project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply the gradient effect, for example, if my mouse passes a grid cell it will light at first but the more I move my mouse towards that particular cell it will gradually get lighter. Here is my project https://repl.it/@antgotfan/etch-a-sketch and here is a working example (not mine btw),  https://codepen.io/beumsk/pen/dVWPOW (just click on the gradient and will see the effect)

I am trying to use "this" and event.target to solve this problem but it is not working. I also tried to use fadeIn with jQuery but it is not my desired effect.

```
 function incrementOpacity() {
     let opacity = 0.1;
     $(".cell").hover((event) => {
         $(event.target).css({"opacity": `${opacity += 0.1}`, 
 "backgroundColor": "#f5f5f5"})
     });
 }
```

In the function, the opacity will increase forever but will stay white.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is setting `let opacity = 0.1;` outside of the `.hover` event. The value should be based off of the cell being hovered, so fetch it inside the event via `event.target.style.opacity`. Also, make sure it is parsed correctly as a `float` to allow correct incrementing (`parseFloat()`):

```
function incrementOpacity() {
    $(".cell").hover((event) => {
        let opacity = parseFloat(event.target.style.opacity);
        $(event.target).css({"opacity": `${opacity + 0.1}`, "backgroundColor": "#f5f5f5"})
    });
}
```

Here is the updated Repl.it for reference: https://repl.it/repls/GreenDigitalWireframe

Couple of optional changes; added check for maximum opacity. Anything over 1 is redundant. Also consider using `mouseenter` for function so opacity is only increased when hovered on, and not hovered off:

```
function incrementOpacity() {    
    $(".cell").mouseenter((event) => {
        let opacity = parseFloat(event.target.style.opacity);
        if(opacity <= 0.9){
          $(event.target).css({"opacity": `${opacity + 0.1}`, "backgroundColor": "#f5f5f5"})
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: For clarification, the reason using `let opacity = 0.1` in conjunction with `${opacity += 0.1}` doesn't work is that in every instance of `.hover`, the value `opacity` was being incremented by `0.1`, but never reset. Essentially, after 9 (or 10) iterations, `opacity` was at a value greater than 1, so each cell was "filled" instantly.

2nd Edit: To prevent issue with assigning multiple handles for the `.hover` (or `.mouseenter`) function, add event unbinding before setting:

```
function incrementOpacity() {
    $(".cell").off("mouseenter");
    $(".cell").mouseenter((event) => { ... });
}

...

function getRandomColors() {
    $(".cell").off("mouseenter");
    $(".cell").mouseenter((event) => { ... });
}
```

Also, make sure the bound event is consistent between the two functions, either `.hover` or `.mouseenter`.

Comment: This really helped a lot but now there is a bug, whenever I click on random and then click on the gradient, the random event is still activated so, the gradient will not work anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, and it was actually present prior to these changes; might be something to do with binding. Let me check.

Comment: Oh wait; I see why. Too different events now; `mouseenter` and `hover`; they need to be the same, whichever fits your use case more.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I am going to try to understand what you did! Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Added an edit now; event unbinding. Basically, remove the handler for `.mouseenter` before assigning it so that there is no conflict. There were two separate functions handling the `.hover` (or `.mouseenter` function), and the code was using the last assigned to handle it.

Comment: So basically the .off() is turning off the event handler for $randomButton? and vice versa for the $gradientButton

Comment: Yup (err well almost; the event handler is on `$(".cell").mouseenter` ) But yeah, it's being called immediately before turning the opposing function back on, but seems to be required when calling the code this way. I would have thought the called handler would override the current one (even if it's the second time being called), but doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It seems I still don't understand what is going (Sorry, I've only been coding with JavaScript for 2 months) but I am gonna try to understand what you did!

Comment: No worries, we all gotta start somewhere. Even after 5 years of working with it, I still have questions :) Feel free to post on Stackoverflow if you need more help, but otherwise, if you need clarification, Google can help you find what's happening with the events/functions you're using (`.mouseenter`, `.off`, etc). Cheers!